# Объясните разницу между echo и print

Tags: php, функции

Объясните разницу между echo и print в php пожалуйста. Я всегда использовал echo при написании кода, скажите если я что-то делаю не так(где надо использовать `print` а не `echo`)

Comment: И почитать руководство тебе конечно же лень?

Comment: там про это не написано

Comment: Серьезно? Может почитаешь повнимательней - https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.print.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поведенческое различие echo и print заключается в том, что последний может вести себя как функция (всегда возвращающая единицу); вследствие этого print можно использовать в контексте, например, тернарного оператора, что иногда может быть весьма привлекательным. Echo как функцию использовать нельзя, зато она может принимать несколько аргументов через запятую, при этом их нельзя брать в скобки; тогда как у print ровно один аргумент, и он может быть как в скобках, так и без.

см. полную статью статью [ТУТ](https://habr.com/ru/post/22951/#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5%20echo%20%D0%B8%20print,%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC.)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Пчелобав Если вам ответ помог - примите ответ (поставьте галку напротив).